# Report server ui?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, user-interface, reporting-services

I have no idea if I actually do it right (Its the 2nd time I work with this for school)

I have to go to the reportservice
http:// localhost /Reportservice
and from there I have to work with a few things, BUT... my screen doesnt even look close on how it should look like, so i'm wondering if I may have messed up somewhere..

their example:
http://s15.postimg.org/gal593adn/their.png

My screen: 
http://s15.postimg.org/5ceh4nb63/mine.png

anyone might know what I have done or havn't done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changhing localhost/reportserver to localhost/Reports

the "reports" part is the name of the sql server instance. If you did not do anything to specify a custom instance name it will be the default - Reports - If you gave the sql server instance your own name, then thats what you'll need to change "reportserver" to.

Comment: Oke I just did this and it works, so I did mess it up somewhere.
Thanks a lot! :)